# How to create ellipse shapes in box2d?

Tags: c++, box2d, shapes

I need to create ellipse shape for the body, and do not understand how to make that in box2d.

Any ideas how to do that **not** by using `b2PolygonShape` with a lot of vertexes.

Comment: There is an egg-shape in one of these demos, maybe you could check out how he did that: http://www.sideroller.com/wck/

Comment: "Defines a “stretchable” circle. If the height and width are the same, a regular circle shape is used. Otherwise a polygon approximation is created."
It from documentation of world-construction-kit. I hoped they done smth new...

Comment: I posted an answer...sorry it took a while...had to think a bit...

Answer (score 6):

**OPTION #1**

Use a body with two fixtures:  The first would be a central circle shape to give the body some mass.  The second would be the ellipse, with the vertices made from a chain shape.

The first fixture allows you to have the body act like a body with some mass, while the second fixture will allow you to handle collisions properly.

I did an example for a roulette wheel recently.  I posted the code below to create that.  Replace the constant value for the radius (OUTER_RADIUS) with the polar form of the radius for an ellipse [found here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center).

```
void MainScene::CreateBody()
{
   const float32 INNER_RADIUS = 2.50;
   const float32 OUTER_RADIUS = 3.0;
   const float32 BALL_RADIUS = 0.1;
   const uint32 DIVISIONS = 36;

   Vec2 position(0,0);

   // Create the body.
   b2BodyDef bodyDef;
   bodyDef.position = position;
   bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
   _body = _world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
   assert(_body != NULL);

   // Now attach fixtures to the body.
   FixtureDef fixtureDef;
   fixtureDef.density = 1.0;
   fixtureDef.friction = 1.0;
   fixtureDef.restitution = 0.9;
   fixtureDef.isSensor = false;

   // Inner circle.
   b2CircleShape circleShape;
   circleShape.m_radius = INNER_RADIUS;
   fixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
   _body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

   // Outer shape.
   b2ChainShape chainShape;
   vector<Vec2> vertices;
   const float32 SPIKE_DEGREE = 2*M_PI/180;
   for(int idx = 0; idx < DIVISIONS; idx++)
   {
      float32 angle = ((M_PI*2)/DIVISIONS)*idx;
      float32 xPos, yPos;

      xPos = OUTER_RADIUS*cosf(angle);
      yPos = OUTER_RADIUS*sinf(angle);
      vertices.push_back(Vec2(xPos,yPos));
   }
   vertices.push_back(vertices[0]);
   chainShape.CreateChain(&vertices[0], vertices.size());
   fixtureDef.shape = &chainShape;
   _body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
    
}
```

You can also check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093032/how-to-create-a-circle-shape-without-solid-polygon-or-non-solid-circle/20519366#20519366) for the roulette wheel (plus picture goodness) solution.

**OPTION #2**
Instead of using a chain/edge shape, you can create a triangle fan of fixtures. Once you have the vertices for the ellipse, you could do something like:

```
b2Vec2 triVerts[3];
triVerts[0] = Vec2(0,0);
for(int idx = 1; idx < vertices.size(); idx++)
{
   b2PolygonShape triangle;
   fixtureDef.shape = &triangle;
   // Assumes the vertices are going around
   // the ellipse clockwise as angle increases.
   triVerts[1] = vertices[idx-1];
   triVerts[2] = vertices[idx];
   triangle.Set(triVerts,3);
   _body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
}
```

Was this helpful?

Comment: Sounds like this should be more prone to issues (stuff can more easily tunnel inside the chain than get stuck in the "seams" in a polygon shape, plus no "seams" exist if the polygon based body is a single polygon fixture) and less elegant than using the very same chain geometry to define a polygon. Though, there is the b2_maxpolygonvertices limit to contend with, beyond which you need to use multiple fixtures to define the ellipse. Furthermore, what is the point of the circle anyway? Just set the mass directly and throw away the completely unused circle shape.

Comment: If you read the notes in the Box2dCode, is says: "You cannot increase this too much because b2BlockAllocator has a maximum object size." for the b2_maxPolygonVertices definition.  Also, you can set objects as "bullets" and used fixed time steps to cut down on the tunnel likelihood.  No solution is perfect.  But this should work.

Comment: Maybe you don't need the circle...I thought you could not set mass for a chain shape...I'll check on that.

Comment: For the roulette wheel, the mass remained the same (19.63...) both with and without the outer chain shape.

Comment: Well, there is some method (i never had reason to use it, but I know it's gotta allow this to be set) to assign the mass and inertia to a body regardless of fixtures. Using a circle will set an underestimate for the inertia (and itd be less dense than as specified). At any rate, it's still a great answer, i'm nitpicking.

Comment: You can use SetMassData for a body to explicitly set the mass, rotational inertia, and position of the CM.  I have something of a blind spot for using it because I like to let the system manage those things and don't want to worry about what I changed when as bodies are broken up or created or welded together.  I think the triangle fan will probably be the best solution (Option #2).  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Triangle fan is probably more fixtures and redundant geometry than necessary. Use an "octagon fan". Makes the function slightly more complex though.