# How to create a circle shape without solid polygon or non solid circle``

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am developing a casino roulette game in box2d. As you know in this game a ball/dice will be in a circular spinning wheel.

First I tried with b2circleShape but it didn't work. I mean that the ball is not sitting inside the circular shape.

Then I tried with b2EdgeShape. But for the b2edgeShape I need to create as many vertices as I can to build a smooth circular surface.

Is there anyway that I can create such circle shapes which are not polygons or which are not solid polygons?

If have any solution please let me know

Comment: you can only do this with an edge or better chain shape to form the wheel rim. If it needs 100 vertices so be it.

Comment: in case you don't know: you can link multiple chain shapes together to form an arbitrarily complex surface. You're not limited to the fixed number of vertices in a single chain shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a single body for the roulette wheel.  Use a circle shape for the "inner" part of it and a chain shape for the "outer" part of it.

You should probably use "spikes" in the chain shape to add something for the ball to bounce off of.  Here is the main creation function:

```
void MainScene::CreateBody()
{
   const float32 INNER_RADIUS = 2.50;
   const float32 OUTER_RADIUS = 3.0;
   const float32 BALL_RADIUS = 0.1;
   const uint32 DIVISIONS = 36;

   Vec2 position(0,0);

   // Create the body.
   b2BodyDef bodyDef;
   bodyDef.position = position;
   bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
   _body = _world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
   assert(_body != NULL);

   // Now attach fixtures to the body.
   FixtureDef fixtureDef;
   fixtureDef.density = 1.0;
   fixtureDef.friction = 1.0;
   fixtureDef.restitution = 0.9;
   fixtureDef.isSensor = false;

   // Inner circle.
   b2CircleShape circleShape;
   circleShape.m_radius = INNER_RADIUS;
   fixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
   _body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

   // Outer shape.
   b2ChainShape chainShape;
   vector<Vec2> vertices;
   const float32 SPIKE_DEGREE = 2*M_PI/180;
   for(int idx = 0; idx < DIVISIONS; idx++)
   {
      float32 angle = ((M_PI*2)/DIVISIONS)*idx;
      float32 xPos, yPos;

      xPos = OUTER_RADIUS*cosf(angle-SPIKE_DEGREE);
      yPos = OUTER_RADIUS*sinf(angle-SPIKE_DEGREE);
      vertices.push_back(Vec2(xPos,yPos));

      xPos = OUTER_RADIUS*cosf(angle)*.98;
      yPos = OUTER_RADIUS*sinf(angle)*.98;
      vertices.push_back(Vec2(xPos,yPos));


      xPos = OUTER_RADIUS*cosf(angle+SPIKE_DEGREE);
      yPos = OUTER_RADIUS*sinf(angle+SPIKE_DEGREE);
      vertices.push_back(Vec2(xPos,yPos));
   }
   vertices.push_back(vertices[0]);
   chainShape.CreateChain(&vertices[0], vertices.size());
   fixtureDef.shape = &chainShape;
   _body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

   // Create some "spikes" for the ball to bounce off of.

   // Start it spinning
   _body->SetAngularVelocity(M_PI/8);

   // NOW create a ball to bounce around inside...
   bodyDef.position = Vec2((INNER_RADIUS+OUTER_RADIUS)/2,0);
   _ballBody = _world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
   circleShape.m_radius = BALL_RADIUS;
   fixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
   _ballBody->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

   // Give it some velocity so it starts to bounce.
   _ballBody->SetLinearVelocity(Vec2(-0.5,0.5));
}
```

This is what it looks like:  [image]

I created a demo of this.  Give the ball some initial velocity and it will bounce a little, but quickly becomes stuck on the outside (centrifugal force?).  To make this work, you will probably need to keep exciting the ball to make it bounce for a while, till you make it "attract" to a well/sensor point where you want it to end up.

Or you could use a second chain fixture a little inside the outer chain, which is "smooth".  Then remove it when you want the ball to settle down.  No matter what, you will need to use forces to keep the ball moving for a bit till you want it to settle down if you want it to look like a roulette ball in play.

I posted the entire project (Cocos2d-x, c++) to github [here](https://github.com/NonlinearIdeas/RouletteWheel).

You can find articles about using Box2d on my site [here](http://www.nonlinearideas.com).

Was this helpful?

Comment: the reason it's stuck on the outside next to a spike is because you failed to account for the sloped conical shape of a real roulette wheel and the perpendicular force of gravity. also the inside edge of a roulette wheel is smooth and has no spikes......

Comment: @StevenLu Thanks for your feedback.  The original request to create the shape of the roulette wheel.  I wasn't particularly focused on the full simulation of the physics.  The code is posted on github and you are welcome to contribute to it, enhancing its value for everybody...