# Creating a simple hollow rect with vectors

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

Using `box2d` (`+cocos2d` iPhone) , i have to create a simple rect , that will be hollow- that means having a square , that i can put bodies into it (like a cage ) .
I need to create that body with 4 `B2VEC` vectors .
How do i code that ?

The `box2D` says that :

```
Polygons are solid and never hollow
```

1. how can i create a hollow square
2. how do you code that with 4 `b2vec2`

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , you can do it with a chain shape for example(docs) :

```
b2Vec2 vs[4];

vs[0].Set(1.7f, 0.0f);

vs[1].Set(1.0f, 0.25f);

vs[2].Set(0.0f, 0.0f);

vs[3].(-1.7f, 0.4f);



b2ChainShape chain;

chain.CreateChain(vs, 4);

//than construct a body with this fixture
```

Answer (score 0):

A chain shape is the way to go.  [Take a look at this post which explains how to create a roulette wheel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093032/how-to-create-a-circle-shape-without-solid-polygon-or-non-solid-circle)  It is similar in that you want to have objects "inside" other objects.