# cocos2d + box2d: rounded edges in a physical object

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

Prompt, please, as it is possible to have rounded edges on the physical object that is represented vvide vertices?
For example, there is a regular rectangle, that's how it is described:

```
b2Vec2 vertices[] = {
        b2Vec2(0.0*_scale/PTM_RATIO,0.0*_scale/PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(512.0*_scale/PTM_RATIO,0.0*_scale/PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(512.0*_scale/PTM_RATIO,32.0*_scale/PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(0.0*_scale/PTM_RATIO,32.0*_scale/PTM_RATIO)
    };
```

As anything can round out his edge?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using a polygon shape and the vertices set up to represent the rounded corners. However this may require increasing Box2D's internal limit of (if I remember correctly) 8 vertices per polygon.

Alternatively you can use a rect shape and 4 circle shapes, one at each corner. However the placement of the circle shapes will never be such that the rectangle's corners won't stick out of the circles, respectively the circles aligning perfectly with the rectangle's sides.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how much rounding you need.

You can use a polygon shape with more vertices, but this would require increasing the internal limit, which increases the default storage for **ALL** polygon shapes.

You can use an octagon with some circles overlapping on the corners.  You could build this out of two polygons, one for the top and one for the bottom (5 sides each, like a rectangle with the two corners replaced by 45 degree slopes).

However, I think the best approach is to use an ChainShape.  You can create ***LOTS*** of vertices.  In one SO question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093032/how-to-create-a-circle-shape-without-solid-polygon-or-non-solid-circle)), I created a roulette wheel using one of these.  Code and demonstration available with the link.  It was definitely circular enough for most needs.

Was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I have just started learning Cocos2d-x so this may not work, but I think you could anchor and pin nodes together to create N edge circles of desired radius, and N edges from suitable tangent points on circles, where N is the number of corners you want (in OP case for rectangle 4).

Something like this for a rounded corner box, N=4:

- 4 child nodes with circle edge physic body at corners.
- 4 child nodes with straight edge physic body, *ending at tangent points on circles*
- There is supposed to be function to join physic bodies or perhaps physics edges together

```
  __
 O  O
|    |
 O__O
```